# Magento 2: move mini-login dropdown to home page (header)

Tags: magento2, login

There is a mini login form on the checkout page.

How can I move it to the header so it displays on every page?

Comment: Follow the tutorial on how to create mini drop-down login at  http://inchoo.net/magento/create-magento-dropdown-login/

Comment: Any real solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a temporary solution. See https://github.com/eric128/magento2-minilogin
This is not the mini login on checkout page but something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, a simple check for the block to change the ( Sign in ) to ( Sign Out ) would be great.

Something like:

```
if ($block->isLoggedIn()) {
   echo "sign out";
} else {
  echo "sign in";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we're happy to see new contributors. In the future might I suggest when you post to be a bit more precise, or at least add valid PHP?

Answer (score 0):

To move the mini login form from the checkout page to the header in Magento 2, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a custom module or use an existing module to override the customer_account_login layout block.
2. Create a new layout XML file in your module's view/frontend/layout directory with the following content:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" before="header.links" />
            <move element="customer.form.login.mini" destination="header.panel" before="minicart" />
        </body>
    </page>
   ```

This XML code will move the mini login form to the header.panel container and position it before the mini cart in the header.

3. This XML code will move the mini login form to the header.panel container and position it before the mini cart in the header.